# Algolia Import Statements aren't working (Kotlin/Algolia)

Tags: kotlin, import, algolia, instantsearch

Some of the import statements and code specified by the tutorial is highlighted as incorrect. Algolia instantsearch Android documentation can be found [here](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/building-search-ui/getting-started/android/). I dont understand why I keep receiving the following errors. Any guidance would help.

[Issue #1[][2]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2nOy.jpg)